# How to forward port 80 to another port on the samemachine?

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding

How can I forward requests coming in on port 80 to another port on the same linux machine?

I used to do this by changing `nat.conf`, but this machine that I'm using doesn't have NAT. What's the alternative?

Comment: No NAT whatsoever or just no nat.conf? Have you tried any iptables rules using NAT?

Answer (score 58):

You can accomplish the redirection with iptables:

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: +1. Being doing this for years

Comment: How about on Windows Server?

Comment: Oh man this is exactly what I was looking for, kudos!

Comment: Didn't work for me at first, but was fine when I used `sudo`

Comment: what to do if no eth0 interface?  why not use loopback interface?

Comment: Third one did the trick for me as always.

Answer (score 25):

Just found myself in this question and couldn't find an easy way. Don't want to install Nginx in my machine to do this simple port forwarding.

`Rinetd` didn't work for me, no working package for my distro. I went for `socat` instead. Super simple:

```sh
socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:5000
```

Must be ran as `root` to be able to listen on port `80`.

Comment: Rinetd setup is easier I think.

Comment: socat works perfectly!

Comment: I don't know how to make `socat` close the socket when interrupted with ctrl+C, so this solution used verbatim will fail for some time after `socat` is ctrl+C interrupted, but as a quick hack it's possible to add `reuseaddr` to it to avoid [this error](https://serverfault.com/q/329845/519406). Also use port 443 instead of 80 to forward HTTPS

Answer (score 11):

You should look at using a **reverse proxy**, such as **Nginx**. For example, you might put something like this in your `nginx.conf` file:

```sh
server {
    listen         80;

    server_name    your_ip_address your_server_name

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/your_domain/access.log ;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/your_domain/error.log info ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;   # pass requests to the destination
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? I don't neccessarily disagree but is there a good reason you wouldn't want this to just happen™ in the networking stack?

Comment: @Oli This reverse proxy method will not affect numerous other virtual hosts on the server, which would occur if iptables would do it since iptables knows  nothing of virtual hosts.