# What process does 'own' socket in 'Time Wait' state?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-networking

**Main question**
I see following line in netstat. Does it means this socket doesn't belong to any process?

```
#>netstat -tpn|grep TIME_WAIT| head -1
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:5555       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:45845      TIME_WAIT   -
```

**Extra question**

In an multithread program can thread responsible for dealing with socket be already gone? (It's NOT in 'sleep' or 'uninterpretable sleep')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No process owns that socket, the kernel keeps it around for possible cleanup. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait) and [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sockpit/#N100F5) explain more about the TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: Thanks Dennis ;).  Saying about articles on TIME_WAIT there is another one: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html