# reliable systemd service for autossh

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, systemd

I try to create a reliable systemd service for autossh.

The service works, but if the host-keys changes, the service is in state ok (running).

I want it to be in state "failed" if the tunnel does not work.

Here is my current systemd service file:

```
# Source is in srv/salt/tunnel/autossh\@.service
# which is a git repo.
# Don't edit /etc/systemd/system/autossh\@.service  
[Unit]
Description=Tunnel For %i
After=network.target

[Service]
User=autossh
# https://serverfault.com/a/563401/90324
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -o "ConnectTimeout=1" -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 40443:installserver:40443 -R 8080:installserver:8080 tunnel@%i
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the output of `systemctl status autossh@foo-work`

```
salt:/srv # systemctl status autossh@foo-work
autossh@foo-work.service - Tunnel For foo-work
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/autossh@.service; enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Wed, 2016-02-10 14:35:01 CET; 2 months and 3 days ago
    Main PID: 17995 (autossh)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/autossh@.service/foo-work
          └ 17995 /usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -o ExitOnForwardFailure yes -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ServerAliveInterval 60 -o ServerAliveCountMax 3 -R 40443:installserver:40443 -R ...

Apr 14 12:35:43 salt autossh[17995]: Host key verification failed.
Apr 14 12:35:43 salt autossh[17995]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
Apr 14 12:45:42 salt autossh[17995]: starting ssh (count 618)
Apr 14 12:45:42 salt autossh[17995]: ssh child pid is 22524
Apr 14 12:45:43 salt autossh[17995]: Host key verification failed.
Apr 14 12:45:43 salt autossh[17995]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
```

My problem is not the changed host-key. That's ok.

I just want the service to tell me the truth: If the tunnel is not working, then I want it to see it.

How can I change the systemd service file to tell me the correct status?

Update: I wrote a second follow-up question: [How does systemd decide if a service is ok or not](https://serverfault.com/questions/770497/how-does-systemd-decide-if-a-service-is-ok-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that it is failed, but that it is considering service active, because it will be restarted in next 10 minutes.

I didn't try that, but it might work. Try to add `Type=forking` and `PIDFile`

```
[Service]
...
Type=forking
Environment="AUTOSSH_PIDFILE=/path/to/pid"
PIDFile=/path/to/pid
```

With `simple` services, `systemd` can have problems to track them.

Comment: Yes: "The problem is not that it is failed, but that it is considering service active". But switching to type forking does not change this, or I am missing something. I guess autossh should not do any retrying. If it fails on error, then systemd knows that something is wrong. It is up to systemd to do the restarting. AFAIK systemd things everything is alright as long as the process is running.