# Port already in use by process that does not exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port

Trying to run service that uses port results in error

```
Port 20102 is already being used by another process (pid: 821)
```

Though process is not active: `ps ax | grep 821` gives nothing

`netstat -a | grep 20102` gives nothing as well

How is it possible and what can be done?

Comment: It sounds like the socket is in timed-wait. Was 821 active recently and does the problem go away after a few more minutes? if so, this answer covers the problem well https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait

Answer (score 6):

Try change you netstat arguments for

```
netstat -ntupl | grep :20102
```

And use the command for check process in use

```
lsof -i :20102
```

The manual of netstat, on **-a** argument say: All, but this is not true always